# componentWillReceiveProps is invoked not in the current screen react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using `react-navigation` and `createStackNavigatior` to handle my navigation in the app.
In the main loading screen I use `componentWillReceiveProps` to handle results coming from my reducer.

The problem occurs when I navigate away from the loading screen and whenever the same prop is updated in a different screen, the `componentWillReceiveProps` is invoked in the main loading screen that I already navigated from although I expect it not to run at all.

Is there a way to disable that function from firing after it is supposed to be unmounted?

Answer (score 2):

when you `navigate` from a screen to a screen in a `stack navigator`, the previous screen(s) stay mounted

You can either totally unmount the screen by using `this.props.navigation.replace('routeName')` instead of using `navigate` or prevent the prev screen from updating:

From the official docs of React Navigation:

> React Navigation emits events to screen components that subscribe to
>   them. There are four different events that you can subscribe to:
>   `willFocus`, `willBlur`, `didFocus` and `didBlur`. Read more about
>   them in the [API reference](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle).

so try on `willBlur` to stop your component from firing the event of `componentWillRecieveProps`. You can set a flag that is false when `willBlur` is invoked and check it when recieving props and preventing any update from firing